# if we click on Custom Section Header in UITableView, then move that section to top

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `Custom Section Header` in `UITableView`, on that section header there placed `UIButton` on its very right.What i want is, if i click on `UIButton`, that particular `Section Header` should scrolls to Top. That's it

Any suggestion, piece of code will be admired.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Step 1:** set the size of Section header. Example as follows.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 55;
}
```

**Step 2:** create & return the customized section header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *aView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
    [btn setTag:section+1];
    [aView addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return aView;
}
```

**Step 3:** return number of sections. ( for example 10 here )

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 10;
}
```

**Step 4 :** number of rows per section. ( for example, 4 rows for each section )

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}
```

**Step 5 :** create & return cell (UITableViewCell for each Row)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i_%i",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Step 6:** add the event to handle the **TouchDown** on section header.

```
- (void)sectionTapped:(UIButton*)btn {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:btn.tag-1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: method from UITableView.
Set the button tag to the section and call in his action:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:button.tag] 
atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for co0o0ol reply, et really really works for me.. :-)